# Como adicionar atributos a um elemento que foi criado com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Criei um `elemento` com JavaScript:

```
 $("<div />").addClass("placeholder").appendTo(element);
```

Mas não consigo dar atributos a ele, como posso fazer isso? Tentei o seguinte código, mas não funciona:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".placeholder").addClass("fg-red");
 });
```

Se eu crio ele com HTML funciona porém quando eu crio com JavaScript a tentativa de adicionar atributos não funciona

Comment: Isso aqui está errado `addClass(".placeholder")`. Não precisa do ponto antes para indicar que trata-se de uma classe, a função `addClass` serve exclusivamente para isto.

Comment: Desculpe não é o código verdadeiro digitei por celular e nas pressas saiu errado e não vi, desculpa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No momento que anexa o novo objeto `<div />`, apenas adicione as classes que deseja:

## Exemplo 1

```
obj = $("<div />"); 
obj.addClass("placeholder");
obj.addClass("fg-red");
obj.appendTo(element);
```

## Exemplo 2

```
$("<div />").addClass("placeholder").addClass("fg-red").appendTo(element);
```

## Exemplo 3

```
$("<div />").addClass("placeholder fg-red").appendTo(element);
```

Comment: Este exemplo não funciona, ele está dentro de uma função o que eu acredito que não tenha como usar variáveis de funções

Comment: Nesse caso vou marcar a pergunta como não clara o suficiente. E também não ficou claro o que quis dizer no comentário. `...está dentro de uma função o que eu acredito que não tenha como usar variáveis de funções `

Comment: A sua resposta está de acordo com a minha pergunta, mas apenas gostaria de saber como posso fazer isso já que a criação do elemento está dentro de uma função no meu caso

Comment: coloque isso na sua pergunta. Alias, isso já se torna numa  questão secundária. Abra outra pergunta específica.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/238685?noredirect=1

Answer (score 1):

Escrevi algo para você analisar, para manipular elementos criados dinamicamente utilize a função **ON do Jquery** ([vide documentação](http://api.jquery.com/on/))

```
<html>
    <head>

        <style>
            .verde {
                background:#0f0 !important;
            }

            #teste-area{
                background:#ccc;
                max-width:300px;
                min-height:100px;
            }

            .elemento {
                background:red;
                min-height:50px;
                margin: 5px;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            <a href="#" id="criar">Criar Elemento</a>
        </p>
        <p>
            <a href="#" id="add">Adicionar Atributo ao Elemento Dinamicamente</a>
        </p>

        <div id="teste-area"></div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){    
                $('#criar').click(function(e){
                    console.log("nojento");
                    $("<div><center>Elemento Adiciona</center></div>").addClass("elemento").appendTo($('#teste-area'));
                });

                $('body').on('click','#add', function(e){
                    $(".elemento").addClass("verde").empty().html("<center>Elemento Alterado Dinamicamente</center>");     
                    });
            });
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

É porque seu objeto está sendo criado dinamicamente,  use:

```
$(document). on (function (){
      ... aqui o que você quer fazer, no caso o addClass

}
```

Comment: O ready só atribui os eventos ao término do carregamento da página, em nenhum outro momento

Comment: Trocar o `ready` pelo `on` não funcionou, nem com o elemento já criado

Comment: Com os elementos já criados o ready é necessário manter, agora para os criados dinamicamente vou pesquisar melhor