# Acessar variável dentro e fora de uma função

Tags: javascript, funções, variáveis-globais

É possível acessar uma variável dentro de uma função para fora dela?

Eu gostaria de usar uma variável que foi criada em uma função fora dela, mas sem retornar pelo `return` da função.

No PHP podemos fazer isso

```
$variavel = 123;

function qualquerCoisa(){
    global $variavel;

    echo $variavel;
}
```

Eu quero algo semelhante no JavaScript

```
function qualquerCoisa(){
    var teste = 1;
}

qualquerCoisa();

console.log(teste); // <- Aqui, dá erro porque a variável está dentro da função.
```

Comment: você pode retornar ou usar o global.

Comment: O que você chama de exportar?

Comment: Ele veio no embalo disso aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114377/como-adicionar-atributos-a-um-elemento-que-foi-criado-com-javascript/114407?noredirect=1#comment238687_114407

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No JavaScript o escopo das variáveis depende da palavra reservada `var`.
Se uma variável é criada sem essa palavra ela será global, caso contrário local.

Ex.:

```
function setNome1(nome) {
  nome_usuario = nome; // nome_usuario foi criada no escopo global
}

function setNome2(nome) {
  var nome_usuario = nome; // nome_usuario foi criada no escopo local
}

setNome1('lucas');
alert(nome_usuario); // lucas
setNome2('felipe');
alert(nome_usuario); // lucas
```

Da mesma forma que funções podem criar variáveis no escopo global, é possível acessá-las.

Ex.:

```
var nome = 'matheus';
function getNome() {
    // A variável nome não existe neste escopo.
    // O interpretador irá buscar em no escopo do qual essa
    // função foi definida. Caso não exista, irá buscar no
    // escopo superior, e assim por diante.
    // Caso a variável não exista será lançado um erro
    // ReferenceError: nome is not defined
    //
    return nome; // 'matheus'
}

alert(getNome()); // 'matheus'
```

Qualquer função também pode alterar o valor de uma variável definida no escopo do qual ela foi definida, ou nos superiores.

Ex.:

```
var nome_usuario = 'douglas';
function setNome(nome) {
    nome_usuario = nome;
}

alert(nome_usuario); // douglas
setNome('emilia');
alert(nome_usuario); // emilia
```

Answer (score 3):

Em PHP, para exportar a variável em si teria que declará-la global. É a única forma, mas [não faça isto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49521/101). Em geral variáveis globais só devem ser usadas em PHP em [situações muito específicas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102652/101), e certamente não para exportar uma variável.

Em várias linguagens uma variável global é algo ruim dada a dimensão da aplicação. em PHP não é tão ruim assim porque ela roda como *script*, ainda assim deve-se ter algum cuidado. Mesmo não sendo tão problemática há soluções melhores e é quase impossível ter uma boa justificativa para usar uma variável global para este caso. Então procure uma solução melhor.

Se deseja apenas retornar o valor, então um simples `return` resolverá. Eventualmente se precisa retornar mais de um valor existe a solução de usar um [parâmetro por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51209/101) ou ainda retorna uma estrutura de dados com mais de uma valor (um *array*, por exemplo).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).