# Como obter o valor da variável fora da função?

Tags: javascript, jquery, funções, declaração-de-variável

Como obter o valor da **var DI** para fora da função?
sou novato, e me enrosquei..

eu preciso incluí-la numa outra função mas não consigo obter o valor dela fora :(

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www2.cetip.com.br/ConsultarTaxaDi/ConsultarTaxaDICetip.aspx"
  }).then(function (respomse) {
    var data = JSON.parse(respomse);
    $('#taxaPct').text(data.taxa + '%');
    DI = data.taxa; 
    console.log(DI); <---- Aqui ele exibe no console
  });
});

console.log(DI); <---- Quero acessar ela fora da função
```

Comment: Qual o erro no console do navegador?

Comment: obrigado a todos, utilizei a requisição assíncrona e deu muito bom.

Comment: Olá, essa pergunta [já foi respondida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114493/acessar-vari%c3%a1vel-dentro-e-fora-de-uma-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando que **esteja apenas tentando acessar uma variável fora do escopo ou esteja enfrentando um problema de requisição assíncrona:**

#### Acesso fora de escopo:

Caso esteja tentando acessar uma variável que está fora do escopo da função onde a deseja, você pode declarar ela em um **escopo ao qual ambas as funções tenham acesso**, como no exemplo:

```
var DI = ''; // inicializando com um valor vazio, para que não ocorra um acesso a uma variável não inicializada
$(document).ready(...
```

E ainda conseguirá usar o valor da mesma variável em outra função após ter populado ela.

#### Requisição assíncrona:

Caso o problema seja acessar a variável fora do escopo da requisição porque não possui nenhum valor (mas já havia sido declarada em um escopo externo), você pode fazer uma requisição síncrona da seguinte maneira no `jQuery`:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://www2.cetip.com.br/ConsultarTaxaDi/ConsultarTaxaDICetip.aspx",
    async: false // fazendo com que a requisição seja síncrona; Não haverá execução até que o processo dessa função termine.
  }).done(function (response) {
    var data = JSON.parse(response);
    $('#taxaPct').text(data.taxa + '%');
    DI = data.taxa;
  });
```

Note que não estou usando `then` e sim `done`, dado que [`then` retorna uma nova Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583783/when-should-i-use-jquery-deferreds-then-method-and-when-should-i-use-the-pip) (continuaria sendo tratado posteriormente, de forma assíncrona). Ao fazer com que nada mais aconteça até que a requisição finalize, você deveria conseguir popular a variável da forma que precisa. Isso acontece porque a requisição [está ocorrendo em outro "processo"](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Conceitos), enquanto seu código principal continua rodando. Então ao chegar no uso da sua variável `DI`, ela ainda não foi populada, ou seja, a requisição ainda não recebeu uma resposta.

**Outro detalhe que pode acarretar em problemas é o fato de ter a chamada dentro do [`$(document).ready`], pois pode ser que a função que faz o uso da sua variável `DI` já tenha sido chamada mas a página ainda não carregou completamente.** A função só será chamada no [carregamento completo](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) do [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/DOM/Referencia_do_DOM/Introdu%C3%A7%C3%A3o).

Dito isso, recomendo que reveja o código para evitar chamadas síncronas quando possível, já que todo o código vai esperar a chamada finalizar para continuar e isso é ruim para experiência do usuário, dando a impressão de que algo "travou". Deve ver uma mensagem como a que está abaixo no console do seu navegador ao usar chamadas do tipo:

> [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is
> deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's
> experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Esse tipo de dúvidas é muito comum em pessoas iniciantes. Para conseguir acessar a variável `DI` fora dessas funções de callback, podes fazer duas coisas:

- Ou usas `Promises`:

```
const Promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://www2.cetip.com.br/ConsultarTaxaDi/ConsultarTaxaDICetip.aspx"
    })
      .then(function (respomse) {
        var data = JSON.parse(respomse);
        $('#taxaPct').text(data.taxa + '%');
        const DI = data.taxa; // O `const` é uma forma de criares variáveis "imutáveis" no EcmaScript 6.
        resolve(DI);
        console.log(DI);
      });
  });
});

Promise
  .then(DI => console.log(DI)); // Isto é uma arrow function, mas podes utilizar funções anónimas convencionais.
```

- Ou usas os bons e velhinhos callbacks:

```
function consultarTaxaDi(callback) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://www2.cetip.com.br/ConsultarTaxaDi/ConsultarTaxaDICetip.aspx"
    }).then(function (respomse) {
      var data = JSON.parse(respomse);
      $('#taxaPct').text(data.taxa + '%');
      const DI = data.taxa; 
      console.log(DI);
      callback(DI);
    });
  });
}

consultarTaxaDi(function(DI) {console.log(DI)}); Podes também usar arrow functions.
```

Apesar destes exemplos funcionarem bem eu, no teu lado, processaria essa variável `DI` dentro da função onde tal é declarada.